# Sort div values with "." instead of "," correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use the following script to sort div values, but the problem at this way of sorting is that it only works correctly with numbers if I use a "," instead of "." - is there any way to this with dots?

```
var $divs = $("div.box");

$('#alphBnt').on('click', function () {
    var alphabeticallyOrderedDivs = $divs.sort(function (a, b) {
        return $(a).find("h1").text() > $(b).find("h1").text();
    });
    $("#container").html(alphabeticallyOrderedDivs);
});

$('#numBnt').on('click', function () {
    var numericallyOrderedDivs = $divs.sort(function (a, b) {
        return $(a).find("h2").text() > $(b).find("h2").text();
    });
    $("#container").html(numericallyOrderedDivs);
});
```

At my fiddle you can see that the dates are not correctly sorted if you click on "#numBnt".

[My fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/voh8b7bb/)

Comment: You need to convert the date values to dates object to sort numerically.

Comment: First of all, learn how `sort` works. You should be returning a number, NOT a boolean. Once you've sorted that out, consider `.replace(/(\d)[.,](\d)/g,'$1$2')` or similar to remove punctuation from between numbers. Depending on how it's done, simply `/(\d),(\d)/` or `/(\d)\.(\d)/` would suffice. Or even `parseFloat`...

Comment: @Niet the Dark Absol: Check the JS Fiddle. The values are dates

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie To be honest I didn't notice the fiddle because I got it visually confused with the tags or something XD But that aside, a question should be self-sufficient, not relying on an external fiddle to actually see what's happening.

Comment: Where is the `,`?? Am I missing something?

Comment: the problem is sorting alphabetically?

Comment: @Rahul Desai: there is no "," in my example, because "," works, but "." doesn´t work and I need "."

Comment: I tried in your link and the dates are sorted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the text with dates into JS `Date` object like this:

`new Date( $(a).find("h2").text() )`.

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/voh8b7bb/2/)

JS:

```
var $divs = $("div.box");

$('#alphBnt').on('click', function () {
    var alphabeticallyOrderedDivs = $divs.sort(function (a, b) {
        return $(a).find("h1").text() > $(b).find("h1").text();
    });
    $("#container").html(alphabeticallyOrderedDivs);
});

$('#numBnt').on('click', function () {
    var numericallyOrderedDivs = $divs.sort(function (a, b) {
        // here is the change:
        return new Date($(a).find("h2").text()) - new Date($(b).find("h2").text());
    });
    $("#container").html(numericallyOrderedDivs);
});
```

Try playing around with different dates to test the fiddle.

Also go over [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10124053/586051).

---

**EDIT:**

Fix for Firefox:

Firefox doesnt like `.` as the delimeter in dates. It needs to be replaced by `/`.

`new Date($(a).find("h2").text().replace(/\./g, '/'))`

[**Updated fiddle for Firefox**.](http://jsfiddle.net/voh8b7bb/3/)

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8490907/javascript-sort-not-working-in-firefox)

Comment: Is it right, that it just work once? - if I click on #alphBnt and then on #numBnt again, it doesn´t work?

Comment: @Pepe It works perfectly for me. Maybe its your cache?

Comment: In chrome the numbers are wrong and on IE and Firefox it doesn´t work correctly (buttons dead) ;(.

Comment: @Pepe Please checkout my edit above. Tested in Firefox but not on IE. I dont have IE.

Comment: Thx for your support and update - that´s it, works fine! Big thx!

Answer (score 0):

Use `parseFloat($(a).find("h2").text().replace(",", "."));` for numbers...

And for dates...

`(new Date($(a).find("h2").text())).getTime()`